# nvarchar data type from sql server can not be uploaded in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, nvarchar

I'm running a stored procedure from sql server in excel file, the result of the stored procedure is fine but not all the columns are uploaded correctly in the excel file,the nvarchar columns from sql server have null values in the excel,
Please what should i do to print the values of nvarchar columns in the excel ?
Many thanks.

Comment: You may need to give a little more info in order for us to help you.  How are you running the stored procedure from Excel; via a data connection, PowerQuery, a VBA macro, etc?  What happens when you run the stored procedure outside of Excel; e.g. if you run it in SSMS?  You mention values are "uploaded" which normally would imply client to server; in this case I think you're talking about pulling data from the DB to Excel though; is that correct?

Comment: I'm using a data connection (get data from microsoft query), when i run the stored procedure in sql server i get the correct results but when i return the data to microsoft excel, the data of type nvarchar have null values, yes i'm talking about pulling daa from the db to excel

Comment: Do you have values in the stored procedure? When there is a null in a result set excel will display that as the string "NULL". Is that what you are talking about? You really need to explain more fully what the issue is here. We are guessing given the huge lack of information.

Comment: @GtariAbir Excel should work fine with nvarchar columns; so something's going wrong.  However it's hard to say what currently.  Could you include a screenshot showing the output from the stored proc when run in SSMS vs what you're seeing in Excel; that may give some clues.

Comment: ps. here's a good post on using this feature; it may help you spot the issue if your configuration's wrong in some way: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/859449/Executing-A-Stored-Procedure-From-Excel-Sheet

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't explain well my problem, i'll try to clarify:i have an excel file with input cell which is a date,i need to print data relative to this date in the same excel(when i change the date,the data that i get from the stored proc change dynamically) so i make a data connection from microsoft query and i defined the cell data as the parameter of my stored proc, now when i execute the stored proc in sql server i get values and all the values are ok but when i excecute it in excel i get null values only with nvarchar columns, the others (date, float ..) are displayed correctly

Comment: Again....do you get a NULL in those columns when running the sql? There is no such thing as a null value in excel. If you see "NULL" it is because the query returned a NULL and excel does not convert that to an empty string.

Comment: No i don't get null when running in sql and in the excel i get empty string

Comment: Could you share the code for your stored proc?  From what you've said it sounds like all should be working; just wondering if seeing the code will give us any additional clues as to what's going on...

Comment: Good Morning, this is a screenshot of the result i obtained when i run my sored procedure in sql server https://imageshack.com/a/img922/1217/E1twFj.png and this is what i get in excel https://imageshack.com/a/img924/3244/h4r2LN.png the code of the stored procedure is as below https://imageshack.com/a/img923/7189/1yWpwe.png